# Changes to the way jQuery stores event bindings and it's impact on fireQuery add-on

Tags: jquery, firebug

Up until jQuery 1.6.4 you could see what events were bound to elements in Firebug when using the fireQuery add-on. Then from jQuery version 1.7 fireQuery stopped displaying the event data. You can still see data which is bound to elements using `$(el).data({})`. I know jQuery used to store the events as a data property, so you could see the events with `$(el).data("events")`.

So my question is...

Why can't fireQuery show event data when using jQuery 1.7+. Has jQuery changed the way it stores event bindings.

It works here...

http://firequery.binaryage.com/test/?v=1.6.4

But doesn't here

http://firequery.binaryage.com/test/?v=1.7.0

Comment: Seems like something you might want to ask the fireQuery authors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see FAQ, second question:
http://firequery.binaryage.com/#faq